# time.clock(), Odd result when used inside function-definition

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-xp

Using the following code (Python 3.3.x, WinXp):

```
## debug function in a general/personal debug include file.
def timer_compare(time1, time2='', note='@', time3=time.clock()):
    print('time1',time1)
    time2 = time.clock() ## same as the function-passed time.clock() (just a little later)
    print('time2',time2)
    print('time3',time3)
    exit(321)
```

Caller code used in the main code file:

```
time0 = time.clock()
## <other unrelated code.>
timer_compare(time0, time.clock())
```

I get the following output:

```
time1 0.0445(snip)
time2 0.0445(snip)
time3 0.0000043(snip) <- 4.385582001116343e-06
```

time3 here seems to have a way to low number.
(It kinda looks like it was pulled from a just newly created timer case.)

What's going on here / what I'm I missing ?

- *I know time.time() is generally preferred/advised over time.clock(), and why.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function defaults are created *at definition time*, not when called.  The `timer_compare` function is an object and defaults are evaluated when it is created and stored as an attribute on that object.

Since your function is created the moment your module is imported (or when your top-level script is first loaded by Python), the `time.clock()` value will be very low.

Use a sentinel instead:

```
def timer_compare(time1, time2='', note='@', time3=None):
    if time3 is None:
        time3 = time.clock()
```

Comment: Aha. I think I get the gist of it. Time to explore the doc's. Thanks (Bedankt, naam genoot. :) )